# push-forward of linear algebraic group schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $\pi: X \to S$ is a proper morphism of schemes, and $G \to X$ is a flat affine algebraic group scheme over $X$. Is the push-forward $\pi_* G$ also affine?

I'd be happy to assume more -- say that $\pi$ is smooth, and that $G$ is smooth over $X$, or even a torus...

Comment: No, it is not affine.  Already for $X\to S$ a smooth, projective morphism whose geometric fibers are connected curves of genus $g>0$, for $G$ the multiplicative group, the pushforward $\pi_*G$ is an extension of an etale group scheme (basically $\mathbb{Z}$) by the relative Jacobian of $X/S,$ and this is an Abelian scheme over $S.$

Comment: @JasonStarr: did you mean to refer to ${\rm{R}}^1\pi_{\ast}(\mathbf{G}_m)$?  For the class of $\pi$ you mention (or more generally smooth proper with geometrically connected fibers of any dimension), $\pi_{\ast}(\mathbf{G}_{m,X})$ is identified with $\mathbf{G}_{m,S}$, as you know.  Likewise, $\pi_{\ast}({\rm{GL}}_{n,X}) = {\rm{GL}}_{n,S}$ for such $\pi$ for any $n > 0$.

Comment: right -- to clarify, I didn't mean $R^1\pi_*$, but just $\pi_*$.

Comment: @nfdc23.  You are completely correct.  I was thinking of $\pi_*(B \mathbb{G}_m)$, the pushforward of the classifying stack, not $\pi_* \mathbb{G}_m,$ the pushforward of the group scheme. Sorry about that!

Comment: What is the motivation for the question?  Already with $S$ a geometric point and $X$ a smooth connected proper curve there will typically be non-split $X$-tori $T$ (arising from units of non-trivial connected etale covers) that admit no non-trivial $X$-point, so $\pi_{\ast}(T) = 1$; that trivial pushforward is affine (even a torus!) but is it something you would consider to be useful?

Comment: To me it's not even clear whether $\pi_* G$ is representable under your assumptions. Is this standard?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn.  Representability follows, for instance, from Lemma 2.3.3 of Max Lieblich's article, "Remarks on the stack of coherent algebras": https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0603034.pdf  I believe that it can also be deduced from Cor. 7.7.8 of EGA $\textrm{III}_2,$ but I cannot quite make that work . . .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry about the mistake in the comment.  First of all, for a proper, locally finitely presented morphism of schemes, $\pi:X\to S,$ with $S$ excellent (e.g., a finite type scheme over a field or over $\text{Spec}\ \mathbb{Z}$), for a finitely presented, flat, affine group scheme $\rho:G\to X$, the set-valued functor $\pi_* G$ is representable by a group <del>scheme</del> **algebraic space** that is locally finitely presented over $S$. (**Ed.** Thanks to @nfdc23 for pointing out that Lieblich's result only gives an algebraic space.) This follows, for instance, from Lemma 2.3.3 of the following article.

MR2233719 (2008c:14022) 
Lieblich, Max(1-PRIN) 
Remarks on the stack of coherent algebras. 
 
Int. Math. Res. Not. 2006, Art. ID 75273, 12 pp. 
 
https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0603034.pdf

However, it is not true that $\pi_*G$ is always affine for $\pi$ a proper, locally finitely presented morphism and $G/X$ a flat, affine group scheme.
Let $S$ be $\mathbb{A}^2_k,$ the affine plane.  The open complement, $j:V\hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^2_k,$ is a flat morphism, but it is not affine.

Let $f:X\to S$ be the blowing up of $\mathbb{A}^2_k$ at the origin. This is a proper morphism. Denote by $E$ the exceptional divisor of $f$. Denote by $U$ the open complement of $E$.  As the complement of a Cartier divisor in a smooth scheme, the open immersion $i:U\hookrightarrow X$ is an affine morphism.

Let $\rho:G\to X$ denote an $X$-scheme with two connected components, one of which maps isomorphically to $X$, $$\rho_e:G_e \xrightarrow{\cong} X,$$ and the second of which maps isomorphically to $U$, $$\rho_{\sigma}:G_{\sigma} \xrightarrow{\cong} U.$$  There is a unique structure of $X$-group scheme on $G$: the identity section is the inverse isomorphism of $\rho_e,$ and the multiplication morphism, $$G_\sigma\times_X G_\sigma \to G_e,$$ is the unique open immersion of $X$-schemes.

The $X$-group scheme $G$ is flat and affine.  Yet the pushforward $\pi_*G$ is a disjoint union of a copy of $S$ and a copy of the open immersion $j:V\to S.$  This open immersion is not affine.

Comment: What I was imagining was that if $G$ sits inside of an affine bundle $A \to X$, where $A$ is the relative $Spec$ of the symmetric algebra of the dual to a vector bundle $V/X$, then the pushforward $\pi_* G$ should sit inside the affine bundle associated to $\pi_* V$. I guess the thing that broke in my intuition was that $\pi_* G$ didn't need to sit inside this as a closed subscheme, but just as something constructible...?

Comment: How does Lemma 2.3.3 of the given link imply the representability? (Note that we don't know if $G$ is a closed $X$-subgroup of some ${\rm{GL}}_n$, say even fppf-locally on $S$.) Olsson's paper on Weil restriction for proper flat maps gives that the pushforward is at least a quasi-separated algebraic space locally of finite type.

Comment: @nfdc23.  Thank you for the correction.  I changed "group scheme" to "group algebraic space."

Answer (score 3):

If $\pi \colon X \to S$ is proper, flat and of finite presentation and $W$ is an affine $X$-scheme, then  $\pi_*W \to S$ is affine and of finite presentation. Unless $W$ is etale over $X$, it is difficult to deduce much about the smoothness of $\pi_*W \to S$.

To see this, you can combine an affine representability result for modules, such as https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08JY or [EGAIII-2, 7.7.8], with the ideas from Proposition 2.5 of:

*Lieblich, Max*, [**Remarks on the stack of coherent algebras**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1155/IMRN/2006/75273), Int. Math. Res. Not. 2006, No. 11, Article ID 75273, 12 p. (2006). [ZBL1108.14003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1108.14003).

A precise reference is Theorem 2.3 of

*Hall, Jack; Rydh, David*, [**General Hilbert stacks and Quot schemes**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1307/mmj/1434731927), Mich. Math. J. 64, No. 2, 335-347 (2015). [ZBL1349.14013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1349.14013).1434731927. https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.mmj/1434731927

Comment: If $W$ is smooth over $S$, and if $\pi$ is proper, finitely presented, and flat of relative dimension $\leq 1,$ then it should be possible to prove smoothness of $\pi_*W\to S$ by infinitesimal deformation theory.  For a geometric point $\text{Spec}\ k\to S$ and for a section $\sigma:X_k\to W_k$, the obstruction space is $H^2(X_k,\sigma^*(\Omega_{W/K})^\vee).$  This is zero if the relative dimension is $\leq 1.$

Comment: The previous comment was wrong.  Again I was thinking of the pushforward of the classifying stack $BG$, not the pushforward of $G.$  For the pushforward of $G,$ the obstruction space is $H^1(X_k,\sigma^*(\Omega_{W/k})^\vee).$  If $W$ is a smooth, linear group scheme of $X$, then there exists a locally free sheaf $\mathfrak{w}$ on $X$ such that $\Omega_{W/k}$ is the pullback of $\mathfrak{w}^\vee.$  Thus, the obstruction space is $H^1(X_k,\mathfrak{w}^\vee).$  This is typically nonzero.  So you were correct: it seems difficult to deduce smoothness (unless $X/S$ is a family of genus $0$ curves).